# Conversion to short from char, odd results?

Tags: c

So my code has in it the following:

> ```
> unsigned short num=0;
> num=*(cra+3);
> printf("> char %u\n",num);
> ```

cra is a char*

The problem is that it is getting odd output, sometimes outputting numbers such as 65501 (clearly not within the range of a char). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for your code to be valid cra has to be a pointer. Can you show us its declaration?

Comment: What are the contents for cra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently `*(cra+3)` is a `char` of value `'\xdd'`. Since a `char` is signed, it actually means -35 (`0xdd` in 2's complement), i.e. 0x...fffffdd. Restricting this to 16-bit gives 0xffdd, i.e. 65501.

You need to make it an `unsigned char` so it gives a number in the range 0–255:

```
num = (unsigned char)cra[3];
```

---

<sub>**Note:**

1. the signedness of `char` is implementation defined, but usually (e.g. in OP's case) it is signed.

2. the ranges of `signed char`, `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` are implementation defined, but again commonly they are -128–127, 0–255 and 0–65535 respectively.

3. the conversion from `signed char` to `unsigned char` is actually -35 + 65536 = 65501.</sub>

Comment: A `char` may also be unsigned. In this case it is not, but in general it may.

Comment: If the char really had the *value* `0xdd`, which is 221, then it would simply remain as 221 when converted to `unsigned short`.  It likely actually has the value -35 (which in two's complement would have the same representation as the unsigned 8 bit value `0xdd`).

Answer (score 2):

`char` is allowed to be either signed or unsigned - apparently, on your platform, it is signed.

This means that it can hold values like -35.  Such a value not within the range representable by `unsigned short`.  When a number out of range is converted to an unsigned type, it is brought into range by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value representable in that type.

In this case, your `unsigned short` can represent values up to 65535, so -35 is brought into range by adding 65536, which gives 65501.

Comment: @Hogan: This doesn't actually rely on the internal representation of the numbers - it's how C is specified to work, regardless of internal representation.  It's a no-op on two's complement machines, but sign-magnitude and ones' complement implementations have to do extra work on signed-to-unsigned conversions to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

`cra` is just a pointer.

It hasn't been allocated any space, by way of `malloc` or `calloc`. So its contents are undefined . `*(cra + 3)` will evaluate to the contents of the location 3 bytes ahead of the location `cra` (assuming `char` occupies 1 byte). I believe that its contents are also undefined.

`unsigned short` takes up 2 bytes, atleast on my system. Hence it can hold values from `0` to `65536`. So, your output is within its defined range

Answer (score 0):

**unsigned short** has a range of (at least) **0 .. 65535** ([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)), the **%u** format specifier prints an **unsigned int** with a range of (commonly) **0 .. 4294967295**. Thus, depending on the value of *cra*, the output appears to be completely sensible.